# mongodb: how to calculate by month difference sessions in percent

Tags: mongodb

My collection `metrics` contains the following data:

```
{ "year" : "2011", "month" : "01", "day" : "1", "sessions" : 10 }
{ "year" : "2011", "month" : "01", "day" : "2", "sessions" : 20 }
{ "year" : "2011", "month" : "01", "day" : "3", "sessions" : 30 }
......
{ "year" : "2011", "month" : "02", "day" : "19", "sessions" : 10 }
......
{ "year" : "2011", "month" : "03", "day" : "20", "sessions" : 100 }
...........
```

I would like to know for each month, the percent of `sessions` increased or decreased compared to the previous month?

Example of results expected

```
2011-01  100%
2011-02  -83% (= (10-60)/60 )
2011-03  +900% (= (100-10)/10 )
```

Is it possible to do this in a mongodb query?

Comment: how much I win or loss sessions with the previous month???   can you  give more information?

Comment: For example, for the months "01"(january) I have 10+20+30 = 60 sessions. The next month "02" (february), I have 10 sessions, so I have  lost 50 sessions compared to January (-83% lost).

Comment: I don't think it is possible with Mongo query. You may have to handle this from client code only.